# Play a sound when a key is pressed 

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Does anybody know if there is any predefined way to play a sound for every letter typed from keyboard into the HTML form?

For example: In a text field if I type Y, website says Y and so on.

Or, what would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 20):

It's easy to play sound, and it's easy to add handlers to key press, but there is no predefined way to link the two operations so you'll have to type your own code.

**1) act on key press**

```
document.onkeydown = function() {
    ...
```

**2 ) play sound**

Add an audio element :

```
<audio id=alarm>
    <source src=sound/zbluejay.wav>
</audio>
```

And execute it with

```
document.getElementById('alarm').play();
```

You could for example build a map linking keycodes to sound element ids :

```
var sounds = {
   88 : 'alarm', // key 'x'
   ...

};
document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var soundId = sounds[e.keyCode];
    if (soundId) document.getElementById(soundId).play();
    else console.log("key not mapped : code is", e.keyCode);
}
```

Yoy may find keycodes [here](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)

Comment: I tried that but apparently the method "play" doesn't exist in the audio tag. I get the following error: " Object [object Object] has no method 'play'" Any ideas?

Comment: Your object isn't an audio element, then.

Comment: Yes, I realized that I had to access one more level in order to access the audio object. Thank you.

Comment: nice and complete answer ... thumbs up!

Answer (score 3):

You must have sound files for all letters and call them play on button press event with JavaScript.

Comment: thanks.. Guess I have to code everything.. Just finished making sound files of all letters now time for action.. thanks mates :)

Comment: Hi, were you able to implement it correctly. How did you manage audio play latency? please share

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a quick script that simplifies the job down to only HTML for you.

```js
(function(){
 var keyElements = document.getElementsByTagName('keysound'),
  i   = keyElements.length,
  keys  = {};
 while (i--){
  var cur  = (keyElements[i].getAttribute('keys')||"").toString().split(''),
   v  = cur.length,
   audio = keyElements[i].getAttribute('src'),
   caseinsensitive = keyElements[i].getAttribute('anycase')!==null?true:false,
   regexp = keyElements[i].getAttribute('regexp')!==null?true:false;
  if (audio){
   while (v--){
        cur[v] = caseinsensitive ? cur[v] : cur[v].toLowerCase();
        
    var src=!regexp?audio:
    audio.replace('${key}', cur[v])
    .replace('${code}', cur[v].charCodeAt(0));
    var ele = document.createElement('audio');
    ele.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(ele);
    (keys[cur[v]] = keys[cur[v]] || []).push(
     ele
    );
    if (caseinsensitive) {
            
     (keys[cur[v].toUpperCase()] = keys[cur[v].toUpperCase()] || []).push(
      ele
     );
    }
   }
  }
 }
  console.log(keys);
 window.addEventListener('keydown',function(evt){
  var clist = keys[evt.key] || [],
   clen = clist.length;
  while (clen--){
   try { clist[clen].play() } catch(e) {}
  }
 });
})();
```

```html
<!-- Demo code example -->
<keysound keys="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" regexp anycase src="https://the-peppester.github.io/styff/keys/${key}.mp3" />
<keysound keys="QWERTY" src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Fart-Common-Everyday-Fart_Mike-Koenig.mp3" />
<keysound anycase keys="bnm,./;'[]-=+_()*&^%$#@!`~" src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Iguana_Farts_In_A_Bathtub-Iguana_Farts-1423164123.mp3" />
<keysound anycase keys="asdfgh" src="http://soundbible.com/mp3/Uuuuuu-Paula-1357936016.mp3" />
```

## Documentation

The script above gives special meanings to the keysound element to allow you to play sounds when a user pushes down on a key. Theese are the special attributes.

- `anycase`

  - makes the keys case insenstive
- `keys=...`

  - the keys that will play this sound
- `regexp`

  - makes it so that the URL of each key can be different in a regexp-like manner like so:
  - `${key}` in the URL will get replaced by the plain text representation of each selected key
  - `${code}` in the URL will get replaced by the base 10 ASCII key code representation of each selected key
- `src=...`

  - determines the URL of the audio file. Is affected by the regexp attribute

See the demo about for examples of these.

Comment: Run the demo and try pressing random keys on your keyboard, its really fun!