# Make a span to play music(mp3) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, mp3

I need your help, because I want to make a `span` to play music. I made a Javascript code and tried to edit the HTML, but the `span` is still not clickable. I am not sure that this would be the best solution for what I want.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="service-box">
        <div class="service-ico">
          <span id="hang1" class="ico-circle"><i class="ion-play"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="service-content">
          <h2 class="s-title">Magyar hangminták</h2>
          <p class="s-description text-center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni adipisci eaque autem fugiat! Quia,
            provident vitae! Magni
            tempora perferendis eum non provident.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is the JS:

```
var hang1 = new Audio();
hang1.src = "hang1.mp3"

$("#myspan").click(function(){
    hang1.play()
})
```

Comment: I think this Stack Answer can also assist you [Play a Sound when a key is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578379/play-a-sound-when-a-key-is-pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to html `<audio>` tag and the sources of music in it.

**HTML**

```
<audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="service-box">
    <div class="service-ico">
       <button onclick="playAudio()" type="button"><span id="hang1" class="ico- 
       circle"><i class="ion-play"></i></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="service-content">
      <h2 class="s-title">Magyar hangminták</h2>
      <p class="s-description text-center">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Magni adipisci eaque 
        autem fugiat! Quia,
        provident vitae! Magni
        tempora perferendis eum non provident.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
var x = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 

function playAudio() { 
  x.play(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it to play the music upon a click;
you need to create the audio object; and hide it

```
<audio id="audio" controls style="display:none">
  <source src="\\youraudio path.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> 
</audio>
```

Then use a `EventListener` for the right key to be pressed:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('audio').play();
  }
});
```

in this example `13` being enter key.

Hope this help.